# Asynchronous JMS

Tags: oracle11g, jms, osb

I'm trying to understand OSB and i have the situation shown in figure.

[image]

JMSProducer is a Business Service that produce a message (request) that is put in RequestQueue

JMSConsumer is a proxy consume the message request

JMSReplyProducer is a Business Service JMSReplyProducer generate a response

JMSReplyConsumer is a proxy that consume the response.

I have problem to set the flow. I'm using OEPE to setup the Oracle Service BUS. I've already create a JMSProducer that send a request to JMSconsume and I let 
JMSConsumer to consume the request. In JMSConsumer i have a pipeline pair and in the request pipeline a node stage with a log.

I don't understand, as shown in Figure, how to put in comunication the JMSConsumer with JMSReplyProducer and let JMSReplyCOnsume to consume the response.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up the queues first
2. The OSB cluster on the left has a proxy service (represented by the circle at the top left)
3. That proxy routes to a JMS-transport business service with URL pointing to RequestQueue, and `Is Response Required` checked, and using the default correlation ID to pull from ResponseQueue
4. On the cluster on the right, create a JMS-transport proxy that reads from RequestQueue, has `Is Response Required` checked, and outputs back to ResponseQueue. You can then fill out that proxy to do whatever you want.